# How to ajax return id of created element?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have this bit of code to add a new `LineProduct`

```
$.ajax({ 
   url: '/line_products',
   data: { 
     line_product:{
        order_id:order_id,
        product_id:product_id,
        count:count
     },
     authenticity_token:authenticity_token 
   },
   type: 'post',
   success: function(result){
     lastCreatedLineProductId = ... ?
   }
})
```

And I'd like to `append` the product to a list, but I need the `id` of it for `edit` button that would also be appended. How could I get the id of this created element?

Comment: whaetver your server-side ajax handler does, part of what it returns to the client would have to be the id of that new product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your controller action return a `json` object after it is completed:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @object }
end
```

So in your success callback you get:

```
success: function(data) {
  lastCreatedLineProductId = data.id;
```